# C++ Always Const Reference in Constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

So consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() = default;

    A(const A& rhs) {
        cout << "Copy was made!" << endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    A data;
    int foo;

    B(A data, int foo) : data(data), foo(foo) {
    }
};

int main() {
    A data;

    B foo(data, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out:

> Copy was made!
>
> Copy was made!

Yes thats right, it copies twice!

The first copy happends when we pass `data` to `B's` constructor.
The second copy happends when we copy `data` from the constructor to the memeber variable.

We know that we can not go under 1 copy (unless we go `heap & pointers`). So why don't we always write:

`B (const A& data, const int& foo, const SomeOtherType& bar, const float& aFloatyNumber)` ... and so on.

I know that it's cheap to pass int, float etc by value. But by always having `const ref` as `Constructor` parameters we will guarantee 1 fewer copies.

Comment: `we will garantie 1 less copy` This only matters if copies are expensive. Copying an `int` is cheap - cheaper than indirection required to access that same `int` via a reference.

Comment: and no one stops you from using `const A& data` instead. For PODs, it doesn't make any difference, probably the compiler optimizes away the indirection and plainly copies the `int` etc.

Comment: Because the semantics you are looking for are move semantics (which come with rvalue-references) not copies.

Comment: Everything in c++ is pass by value "under the hood", something inherited from c. Since references can and are usually implemented using pointers, you still have to copy the underlying pointer for each function call.
It will be more costly than copying an int, since you end up with an indirection at the end of it all.

Comment: We do always use const ref for non trivial types. Unless we're using *move* semantics. And not just for constructors. Unless you specfically *want* a copy.

Comment: In sweden we have say "Small streams make great rivers." That many small things can escalate into bigger things. Won't I save alot of CPU cycles by putting const ref on every constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do **not** move objects you are consuming you actually *should* pass your arguments by references, probably as a `T const&`. If you do consume your argument, you should pass objects of *move-aware* types (i.e., types defining a move-constructor) by value *and* move it. That is, if `A` is move-aware, i.e., has a constructor `A::A(A&&)`, you'd use:

```
B(A data, int foo) : data(std::move(data)), foo(foo) {
}
```

If your types are not move-aware or you don't need to squeez the last bit of performance out of the construction or the types are move-only, you can safely pass objects by `T const&`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has contradiction.

In first case when you pass by value you are making other object using first one that is why constructor is needed to be called again.

Secondly, passing objects as reference and primitives by values is done for size optimization.

If you want to pass int as const ref or pointer that is okay you can do it but are you getting anything out of it.

If you want to copy that value in called function in some other variable then again constructor will be called.

So if you want to store values in called function's local variables, constructor has to be called again irrespective of whether it was passed by value or reference.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types are not copied around when they needn't. They stay on the stack or in a register until the end.